# why does my JSON file contain [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 and nodeJS, and querying a database. I want to copy the queries into a json file. I run into problems with the json file having strings and objects. Why does my JSON file contain:

`[object Object]`

Here is my code:

```
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
if(err) { 
  throw err; 
  }rows.forEach((row) => {
      arr_string = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row));
      fs.writeFile("tempo.json", arr_string, function(err){
    });

      console.log(arr_string);
  });
});
```

I would like to eventually use ajax requests for these entries.

Comment: Do not parse back to object. Simply try `arr_string = JSON.stringify(row);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr_string = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row));
           //^---------^--- This is parsing the string back to a new object.
```

You are parsing the stringified item to a new Object, hence the node.js file writer is trying to write the object to the write stream, resulting in interpreting it as `[object Object]`.

Just omit the `JSON.parse`, so that the stream will effectively be a **string** instance:

```
arr_string = JSON.stringify(row);
```

Additionally, you should aggregate the result and write it only one time, or **append** to the file:

```
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
if(err) { 
  throw err; 
  }
  let _strings = [];
  const newline_separator = ''; // <-- use whatever separator you need.
  rows.forEach((row) => {
      arr_string = JSON.stringify(row);
      console.log(arr_string);
      _strings.push(arr_string);
  });
  fs.writeFile("tempo.json", _strings.join(newline_separator), function(err){});
});
```

Since it's a json, I would suggest you to provide us a more precise input, so that we can guess what the expected result is.

Comment: the problem now with doing that is now the JSON file only writes the last row (and i queried 4) and also I cannot call arr_string.caphi because its not an object anymore

Comment: @DarkLotus I've updated the post, it should post all of the rows. Besides, why do you need to access `.caphi`? Please clarify the desired output and the input, otherwise it's hard to tell what you need to do.

Comment: I need to access `.caphi` so that I may use it in a web app later @briosheje

Comment: this would be the input: { caphi: 'b a r ii d', en: 'post', dialect: 'FES' }
{ caphi: 't i m a n', en: 'rice', dialect: 'BAS' }
{ caphi: '2 3 t i m d', en: 'depend', dialect: 'BAG' }
{ caphi: 't a 3 b aa n', en: 'sick', dialect: 'SAL' }

Comment: Clarify **exactly** what you need to accomplish: what is `.caphi`? **where** do you need to use it? why do you need to save data to the json? is that retrieved later? your question is too broad and unclear at this point, everything pointed to the current question is resolved. Please edit your original question and add the desired output and why you need to use that method specifically and where.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, `.caphi` is an arabic word (in english script), and I want to use it in a web app later for a multiple choice question generator for arabic words, and I intend to use ajax requests for the server side when the user answers the question

Comment: Then that's **another** question, currently unrelated to this one. The script you've posted just takes data from a database and writes it to a json file, there is **no information** about either the client side, either how the server side would handle the request. At this point, I'm wondering why you're writing a JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

I think while storing JSON data into SQLite, you're not stringifying it. If you directly store JSON data into SQLite it'll store like [object Object] format. My suggestion is to stringify the data while storing in SQLite. And while retrieving only parse it. Then your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

`arr_string` is actually not a string, as you JSON.parse d it. Remove the `JSON.parse` call.

Comment: the problem now with doing that is now the JSON file only writes the last row (and i queried 4) and also I cannot call `arr_string.caphi` because its not an object anymore

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string

```
arr_string = JSON.stringify(row);
```

"the problem now with doing that is now the JSON file only writes the last row (and i queried 4) and also I cannot call arr_string.caphi because its not an object anymore"

```
Create an empty array(list) and push each result of query in array.And then 
finally convert it into JSON.
```

sample code :

```
var rows=[{"holla":"bolla"},{"holla":"bolla1"}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` takes JSON object and returns String 
`JSON.parse()` takes String and returns JSON object 

try :

```
rows.forEach((row) => {
  arr_string = JSON.stringify(row); // 'row' data is converted to String
  fs.writeFile("tempo.json", arr_string, function(err){
});`
```